# Simplifying equations in regards to recursive formula

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How do you show that this expression
$$
\frac{3^{n-1}-(-1)^{n-1}}{4} + \frac{3^{n-2}-(-1)^{n-2}}{4}-3\frac{3^n-(-1)^n}{4}
$$

is equivalent to this one:
$$
\frac{3^n-(-1)^n}4\ ?
$$

Comment: I do not believe this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what it works out to.

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{3^{n-1}-(-1)^{n-1}}{4} + \frac{3^{n-2}-(-1)^{n-2}}{4}-3\frac{3^n-(-1)^n}{4}
&=\frac{3^{n-1}-(-1)^{n-1}+3^{n-2}-(-1)^{n-2}-3(3^n-(-1)^n)}{4}\\
&=\frac{3^{n-1}-(-1)^{n-1}+3^{n-2}-(-1)^{n-2}-3^{n+1}-3(-1)^n)}{4}\\
&=\frac{3^{n-1}+3^{n-2}-3^{n+1}-(-1)^{n-1}-(-1)^{n-2}-3(-1)^n)}{4}\\
&=\frac{3^{n-2}(3+1-9)+(-1)^n(-1-1-3)}{4}\\
&=\frac{-5\cdot 3^{n-2}-5(-1)^n}{4}\\
&=\frac{-5}{4}(3^{n-2}-(-1)^n)\\
\end{array}
$

Or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether $n$ is even or odd, $(-1)^{n-1} + (-1)^{n-2} = 0$, so the first two terms are
$$
\frac{3^{n-1}-(-1)^{n-1}}{4} + \frac{3^{n-2}-(-1)^{n-2}}{4} = 
\frac{3^{n-1} + 3^{n-2}}{4} =
3^{n-2} \frac{3+1}{4} = 3^{n-2} 
$$

so the question is asking you to prove that

$$3^{n-2} - 3\frac{3^n - (-1)^n}{4} = \frac{3^n - (-1)^n}{4}$$

Adding $3\frac{3^n - (-1)^n}{4}$ to both sides, we see that the claim is equivalent to

$$3^{n-2} = 3^n - (-1)^n$$

which is definitely not true.